# How do I transfer the value of the inputs from one page to another?

Tags: reactjs

On one page I have two inputs and a button, after clicking on the button goes to the second page, how do I get data from the inputs on the second page?

*navigate(path, { state: { input_value: value }})* ?

---

**index.js**

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Name'/>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Surname'/>
          <button type='submit'>Send</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**getData.js**

```
export const getData = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Name:</h1>
        <h1>Surname:</h1>
      </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: are you using any routing library? like react-router

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a state variable in the App component and then pass the state as a prop to GetData:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
    const nameInput = useRef(null);
    const surNameInput = useRef(null);
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({
        name: "",
        surName: ""
    });
    const sendData = () => {
        // you can do some input validation here
        setFullName({
            name: nameInput.current.value,
            surName: surNameInput.current.value,
        });
    }
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <header className='App-header'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Name' 
                    ref={nameInput}
                />
                <input type='text' placeholder='Surname'
                    ref={surNameInput}
                />
                <button onClick={sendData}>Send</button>
            </header>
            <!-- some more markup here -->
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here's how you pass your data to GetData component:

```
<GetData fullName={fullName} />
```

And then in your GetData component you get the passed props and display them:

```
export const GetData = (fullName) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Name: {fullName.name}</h1>
            <h1>Surname: {fullName.surName}</h1>
        </div>
    )
};
```

You can read more about hooks like useState and useRef [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Comment: `src\App.js
  Line 12:9:  'setFullName' is not defined  no-undef`

SearcaWARNING in src\App.js
  Line 7:12:  'fullName' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
  Line 7:22:  'setfullName' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

ERROR in src\App.js
  Line 12:9:  'setFullName' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: yep my bad, i had a typo and i fixed it now: setfullName => setFullName at line 7

Comment: the warning that says "fullName is assigned a value but never used" is because you haven't declared yout GetData component inside App, just include <GetData fullName={fullName} /> in the App component and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

So this might be Part 1 of an answer.

Taking the code you have, I've put the fields in form tag, then called handleSubmit from the built in onSubmit that is called when you click a button of type='submit' inside a form.

The values is taken from the event parameter (e) of the onSubmit (you can identify these by the 'name' attribute on the input tags) and then I am using useState hook to store the two values.

This would be where part one ends. You have the data, and you can see how it is passed to the GetDate component (the deconstructed props {name, surname} that are passed in.

From there, you should follow the documentation for your chosen router and, if you run into trouble, post the code you've tried and I can continue to help.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GetData } from './GetData';


export function App() {
      const [theName, setTheName] = useState('');
      const [theSurname, setTheSurname] = useState('');

      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
         setTheName(e.target.name.value);
         setTheSurname(e.target.surname.value);
         e.preventDefault();
      }

      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <header className='App-header'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               <input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name'/>
               <input type='text' placeholder='Surname' name='surname'/>
               <button type='submit'>Send</button>
              </form>
          </header>
          <GetData name={theName} surname={theSurname} />
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

Here is a component like your getData function.
I've added it to the App component, just so you can see the values being displayed, but for what you are looking for, you will need to read the documentation for react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";

export const GetData = ({name, surname}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Name:{name}</h1>
        <h1>Surname:{surname}</h1>
      </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, good luck to you